# Volume calculation of 3D numpy array in python?

Tags: python, volume, numpy-ndarray

I have a 3D array a
a is an numpy array of shape of (512, 512, 133)) which contains non zero values in a certain area.

> I would like to calculate the volume of non zero area in this 3D numpy
>   array.

If I know the pixel spacing (0.7609, 0.7609, 0.5132), how the actual volume can be found in python?

Comment: The volume would simply be the number of non-zero entries or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 4):

> The volume of your 3D numpy array equals to the amount of non-zero
> elements times the volume a pixels takes.

To get the [amount of non-zero elements](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) in a numpy array.

```
import numpy as np
units = np.count_nonzero([[[ 0.,  0.],
                           [ 2.,  0.],
                           [ 0.,  3.]],

                          [[ 0.,  0.],
                           [ 0.,  5.],
                           [ 7.,  0.]]])
# will output 4
```

If you know the spacing s between two pixels the volume of a pixel is calculated as the volume of a square (pixel volume) times the amount of pixels you previously determined.

```
volume = units * pow(s, 3)
```

**Update:**

As your spacings (s1, s2, s3) are not equidistant in your 3 dimensions, the volume will change to

```
volume = units * s1 * s2 * s3
# volume = 4 * 0.7609 * 0.7609 * 0.5132
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
import numpy as np
import random
#Not sure how exactly you define input, this is how I approached it:
matrix=np.zeros((1000, 1000, 1000))

for i in range(1000):
    matrix[random.randint(0, 999), random.randint(0, 999), random.randint(0, 999)] = random.randint(0, 10)

x=np.nonzero(matrix) #returns tuple of all non-zero elements (in format [X, Y, Z])
#and the final result - number of non zero elements - based on 1 coordinate (as len(X)=len(y)=len(Z)

print(len(x[0])) #in my case returns => 924
```